# How to merge two parquet files having different schema in spark (java)

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am having 2 parquet files with different number of columns and trying to merge them with following code snippet

```java
Dataset<Row> dataSetParquet1 = testSparkSession.read().option("mergeSchema",true).parquet("D:\\ABC\\abc.parquet");
              
Dataset<Row> dataSetParquet2 = testSparkSession.read().option("mergeSchema",true).parquet("D:\\EFG\\efg.parquet");                    
  
dataSetParquet1.unionByName(dataSetParquet2);
// dataSetParquet1.union(dataSetParquet2);
```

for `unionByName()` I get the error:

```
Caused by: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Cannot resolve column name
```

for `union()` I get the error:

```
Caused by: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Union can only be performed on tables with the same number of columns, but the first table has 7 columns and the second table has 6 columns;;
```

How do I merge these files using spark in java?

**UPDATE :** Example

dataset 1:

```
epochMillis   | one | two | three| four
--------------------------------------
1630670242000 | 1   | 2   | 3    | 4
1630670244000 | 1   | 2   | 3    | 4
1630670246000 | 1   | 2   | 3    | 4
```

dataset2 :

```
epochMillis   | one | two | three|five
---------------------------------------
1630670242000 | 11  | 22  | 33   | 55
1630670244000 | 11  | 22  | 33   | 55
1630670248000 | 11  | 22  | 33   | 55
```

Final dataset after merging:

```
epochMillis   | one | two | three|four |five
--------------------------------------------
1630670242000 | 11  | 22  | 33   |4    |55
1630670244000 | 11  | 22  | 33   |4    |55
1630670246000 | 1   | 2   | 3    |4    |null
1630670248000 | 11  | 22  | 33   |null |55
```

how to obtain this result for merging two **Datasets**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To merge two rows that come from two different dataframes, you first join the two dataframes, then select the right columns according on how you want to merge.

So for your case, it means:

- Read separately the two dataframes from their parquet location
- Join the two dataframes on their `epochTime` column, using a `full_outer` join as you want to keep all rows present in one dataframe but not in the other
- From the new dataframe with all the columns of the two dataframes duplicated, select merged columns using a function `columnMerges` (implementation below)
- *[Optional] Reorder final dataframe by `epochTime`*

Translated into code:

```java
import org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset;
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row;

Dataset<Row> dataframe1 = testSparkSession.read().parquet("D:\\ABC\\abc.parquet");
Dataset<Row> dataframe2 = testSparkSession.read().parquet("D:\\EFG\\efg.parquet");

dataframe1.join(dataframe2, dataframe1.col("epochTime").equalTo(dataframe2.col("epochTime")), "full_outer")
  .select(Selector.columnMerges(dataframe2, dataframe1))
  .orderBy("epochTime")
```

*Note: when we read parquets no need for `mergeSchema` option as for each dataframe we read only one parquet file thus only one schema*

For the merge function `Selector.columnMerges`, for each row, what we want to do is:

- if the column is present in both dataframe, take value in `dataframe2` if not null, else take value in `dataframe1`
- if the column is only present in `dataframe2`, take value in `dataframe2`
- if the column is only present in `dataframe1`, take value in `dataframe1`

So we first build set of columns of `dataframe1`, set of columns of `dataframe2`, and the list of columns from both dataframes, deduplicated. Then we iterate over this list of columns, applying previous rules for each one:

```java
import org.apache.spark.sql.Column;
import org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset;
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row;

import static org.apache.spark.sql.functions.when;

public class Selector {

  public static Column[] columnMerges(Dataset<Row> main, Dataset<Row> second) {
    List<Column> columns = new ArrayList<>();

    Set<String> columnsFromMain = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(main.columns()));
    Set<String> columnsFromSecond = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(second.columns()));

    List<String> columnNames = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(main.columns()));
    for (String column: second.columns()) {
      if (!columnsFromMain.contains(column)) {
        columnNames.add(column);
      }
    }

    for (String column : columnNames) {
      if (columnsFromMain.contains(column) && columnsFromSecond.contains(column)) {
        columns.add(when(main.col(column).isNull(), second.col(column)).otherwise(main.col(column)).as(column));
      } else if (columnsFromMain.contains(column)) {
        columns.add(main.col(column).as(column));
      } else {
        columns.add(second.col(column).as(column));
      }
    }

    return columns.toArray(new Column[0]);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `mergeSchema` option along with adding all the paths of parquet files you want to merge in `parquet` method, as follow:

```java
Dataset<Row> finalDataset = testSparkSession.read()
  .option("mergeSchema", true)
  .parquet("D:\\ABC\\abc.parquet", "D:\\EFG\\efg.parquet");
```

All columns present in first dataset but not in second dataset will be set with `null` value in the second dataset

Comment: Thanks @Vincent Doba. can we not merge datasets? dataSetParquet1 and dataSetParquet2?

Comment: I don't understand your new question. Do you want to union (add row of dataset2 at the end of dataset1) the two dataset after reading separately both of them ? Or do you want to join them (merge rows of dataset1 and dataset2 that have a common id) ? Can you add a small example with sample of dataset1, sample of dataset2 and the final expected output, like in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/68992621/6807769 ?

Comment: I have added an update in the question part , can you please check?

Comment: Thanks for the example, it really explains what you want to do. Please check my new answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/69049569/6807769