# How can I merge two files and add corresponding value in spark?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I hava two files：The first column represents id and the second column represents values.

file1.txt as follow:

```
1 0.1
2 0.2
3 0.3
```

file2.txt as follow:

```
1 0.4
2 0.3
3 0.1
```

How can merge two files and add corresponding values in spark? result.txt as follow:

```
1 0.5
2 0.5
3 0.4
```

Answer (score 1):

You can [Union](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.union.html) the 2 `DataFrames` and [GroupBy](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.groupBy.html) on `id` to generate the sum over the `value` column -

## Data Preparation

```
input_list1 = [
            (1,0.1)
           ,(2,0.2)
           ,(3,0.3)
]

input_list2 = [
            (1,0.4)
           ,(2,0.3)
           ,(3,0.1)
]


sparkDF1 = sql.createDataFrame(input_list1, ['id','value'])
sparkDF2 = sql.createDataFrame(input_list2, ['id','value'])


sparkDF1.show()
+---+-----+
| id|value|
+---+-----+
|  1|  0.1|
|  2|  0.2|
|  3|  0.3|
+---+-----+


sparkDF2.show()
+---+-----+
| id|value|
+---+-----+
|  1|  0.4|
|  2|  0.3|
|  3|  0.1|
+---+-----+
```

## Union & GroupBy

```
combinedDF = sparkDF1.union(sparkDF2)

combinedDF.show()
+---+-----+
| id|value|
+---+-----+
|  1|  0.1|
|  2|  0.2|
|  3|  0.3|
|  1|  0.4|
|  2|  0.3|
|  3|  0.1|
+---+-----+

combinedDF.groupBy('id').agg(F.sum(F.col('value')).alias('value')).show()

+---+-----+
| id|value|
+---+-----+
|  1|  0.5|
|  3|  0.4|
|  2|  0.5|
+---+-----+
```

Answer (score 0):

You can read your two text files as csv files, then join the two read dataframes, sum the two values columns and then save your result dataframe as a csv file.

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.col
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.{DoubleType, IntegerType, StructField, StructType}

// Define schema of the two input files
val schema1 = StructType(Seq(
  StructField("id", IntegerType), 
  StructField("value1", DoubleType)
))

val schema2 = StructType(Seq(
  StructField("id", IntegerType), 
  StructField("value2", DoubleType)
))

// Read the two input files to two dataframes
val dataframe1 = sparkSession
  .read
  .option("delimiter", " ")
  .option("header", "false")
  .schema(schema1)
  .csv("file1.txt")

val dataframe2 = sparkSession
  .read
  .option("delimiter", " ")
  .option("header", "false")
  .schema(schema2)
  .csv("file2.txt")

// Join the two dataframes and save result as one csv file
dataframe1.join(dataframe2, Seq("id"))
  .withColumn("value", col("value1") + col("value2"))
  .drop("value1", "value2")
  .repartition(1)
  .write
  .mode("overwrite")
  .option("header", "false")
  .option("delimiter", " ")
  .csv("/tmp/result")
```

However, you can't chose the name of output file. So if you really want a `result.txt` file, you should rename it afterward:

```sh
mv /tmp/result/*.csv /tmp/result/result.txt
```